# Как сделать map массива?

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Есть массив `Points` состоящий из объектов вида (координаты для отображения на карте):

```
[
  { lat: coordinates[0], lng: coordinates[1] },
  { lat: coordinates[0], lng: coordinates[1] }
]
```

Делаю мапинг массива:

```
points.map((point, idx) => (
  <Placemark
    key={idx}
    geometry={[point.lat, point.lng]}
    onClick={() => this.removePoint(idx)}
  />
));
```

Данные координаты не распознаются картой и не отображаются, но если ввести координаты вручную в `geometry` то точка на карте появится.
В чем ошибка мапинга?

Comment: points: Array(1)
0: Array(1)
0: {lat: 54.98480128623965, lng: 73.38743807421874}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object

Comment: Так а в чем конкретно ошибка? Что значит не распознаются картой? Может быть есть текст ошибки или еще что-то? Не могли бы вы привести в своем вопросе детали, по вашей проблеме.

Comment: Еще по вашему коду есть замечание: использование стрелочной функции в рендере создает новую функцию каждый раз при рендеринге компонента, что может влиять на производительность и приводить к сайд эффектам. Это касается вот этого кода: `() => this.removePoint(idx)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

изменил входящие данные

```
[{ coordinates[0], coordinates[1] },{ coordinates[0], coordinates[1] }]
```

и мап переделал

```
points.map((point, idx) => (<Placemark
key={idx}
geometry={[point[0], point[1]]}
onClick={() => this.removePoint(idx)}  />));
```

точки на карте появились.